# How do I remove empty space created by canDisplayAdBanner?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I added iAd to my application using `self.canDisplayBannerAds`.  The application uses `UITabBarController` and that seems to be causing a problem.  See the "empty" (gray) space in the screenshot below. 
[image]

The `UITextView` has the following constraints:
[image]

And the program is very simple:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}

@end
```

This simple program, with the `canDisplayBannerAds` commented out (or set to NO) doesn't have a gray rectangle at all.  But with ads I can't seem to get rid of that "empty" (gray) rectangle.  Does anyone have a suggestion to resolve this issue?

[Demo project on github](https://github.com/vonbathory/adTest).

Comment: can I see you demo project???

Comment: I added my demo project to github.  First time doing it so I hope I got it right.

Comment: You're too quick.  Just added it.  Sorry should have added my comment after the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your ViewController's TabBar to `Opaque` and your problem will be resolved.

[image]